# How i can update this Setlist of users?

Tags: java, loops, set

I need some help guys. I'm making a chat who read an XML each 10 sec aprox (yeah the database is the XML, congrats my teacher, we can't change database format xDD)

So on, my question now i create the function, replace the messages is easy, if the xml messages are more than RAM one, then i clear the ram and then add all messages again, but i can't do that to users, i don't know why but i think equals or something is broken(? i don't know pls help me my brain is about to break!

```
if (temp.getList().size() > roomList.getList().size()) {
    for (Room room_xml : temp.getList()) {
         if (roomList.addRoom(room_xml)) {
             System.out.println("A room was loaded");
         }
    }
} else {
    for (Room room_xml : temp.getList()) {
         for (Room room_ram : roomList.getList()) {
              if (room_ram.equals(room_xml)) {
                  if (room_ram.getMessageList().size() < room_xml.getMessageList().size()) {
                      room_ram.getMessageList().clear();
                      room_ram.getMessageList().addAll(room_xml.getMessageList());
                  }
                  Set<User> us_xml = room_xml.getUserList();
                  for(User u_xml: us_xml){
                      for(User u_ram: room_ram.getUserList()){
                          if(room_ram.getUserList().add(u_xml)){
                             System.out.println("User was added(?");
                          }
                      }
                   }
                   /*for (User u_xml : room_xml.getUserList()) {
                          if(room_ram.getUserList().add(u_xml)){
                             System.out.println("User was added(?");
                          }else{
                             break;
                          }
                     }*/
```

I share my proyect on github if u need more info about that : https://github.com/Varo95/ChaTerra
This code is on RoomListDAO.java
PD: I put print but i use javafx xd

I got another idea, like declaring actual_user on roomdao and check on xml is on the list to add one....but doesn't seems to work :(

Comment: Sounds more like you want some kind of diff engine/workflow, where you can compare the "database" with the "memory" and figure out the differences and then apply changes as you need

Answer (score -1):

I already resolve it, thanks any way, i already do this and seems to work:

```
RoomList temp = load();
                    if (temp.getList().size() > roomList.getList().size()) {
                        for (Room room_xml : temp.getList()) {
                            if (roomList.addRoom(room_xml)) {
                                System.out.println("Room was loaded on RAM");
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (Room room_xml : temp.getList()) {
                            for (Room room_ram : roomList.getList()) {
                                if (room_ram.equals(room_xml)) {
                                    if (room_ram.getMessageList().size() < room_xml.getMessageList().size()) {
                                        room_ram.getMessageList().clear();
                                        room_ram.getMessageList().addAll(room_xml.getMessageList());
                                    }
                                    room_ram.getUserList().clear();
                                    room_ram.getUserList().addAll(room_xml.getUserList());
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    saveFile(roomList);
```

And saving it too when user left the room or join but i need to make some little fixes more hahahaha well now i feel good with myself